# Proof check and Are these conditions sufficient for p prime to imply p irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-factorization, integral-domain

Let $D$ be an integral domain with a multiplicative norm   $N:D \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$
p|b \implies N(p) \leq N(b) \ \ \ \forall p,b \in D.
$$
with equality only if $b,p$ are associates.

Now I can show the following;

Let   $p \in D$ be prime, that is

$$
\forall u,v \in D,\ \ \ \  p|uv \implies p|u \ \ \ \text{or}\ \ \ p|v
$$

now we claim that $p$ is irreducible in $D$. We prove this by contradiction, so suppose that $p$ is irreducible. Then $p$ has proper divisors in $D$, that is,

$$
\exists u,v \in D:\ \ p =uv.
$$
where $u,v$ are not units or associates of $p$.

Now this means that  $N(p) = N(uv) = N(u)N(v)$ meaning that $N(p)\geq N(u)$ and $N(p)\geq N(v)$.

Now notice that 
$$
p = uv \implies p|uv
$$

but now since $p$ is prime we need $p|u$ or $p|v$. Recall that $u,v$ are not units and in particular not associates of $p$ so we have

$$
N(p)< N(u) \ \ \ \text{or}\ \ \ N(p)<N(v)
$$

which is a contradiction. So we must have that $p$ is irreducible in $D$

**QUESTION**

First of all, is this proof correct? If is not, why not? If it is correct, are there weaker conditions under which the implication

$$
p\  \text{prime} \implies p\ \text{ irreducible}
$$

holds? Also if the proof above is incorrect what are some of the conditions that are also needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an integral domain, it is already the case that every prime element is irreducible (the converse holds in a UFD).

Say $p$ is a prime element of an integral domain $A$. If $p=ab$ then $p|ab$ and hence $p|a$ or $p|b$. WLOG take $p|a$ then $a=pk$ for some $k\in A$, and hence $p=pkb$ and thus $k$ and $b$ are units. This is true for any such $a,b$ and hence $p$ is irreducible.

Your argument essentially contains this argument, but makes use of the unnecessary multiplicative norm.